# Jquery Get method doesn't run the success event

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I've got the following code to read a XML file.

```
function getServiceURL(serviceName) {
    $.get("/xml/ServiceUrls.xml", function(xml){
        $(xml).find("service-name").each(function(){
            if($("service-name").text() == serviceName){
                var url = $("service-name").parent().find("service-url").text();
                return url;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The xml file is some what looks like this!

```
<service>
    <service-title>getAllMajorGroups</service-title>
    <service-url>localhost:9157/getAllMajorGroups</service-url>
    <service-description>Web service to retrieve item major groups</service-description>
</service>
```

When I run the application, the response for the get query is successful.

[image]

but the method doesn't run the success function. I tried with the $.ajax too but the same issue! is any one having the same thing? Anything I'm doing wrong here?

Please help me!

Thank you!

Uptade:

I call the function within another function using the following code.

```
var serviceUrl = getServiceURL("getAllMajorGroups")
```

Comment: where is `service-name` in your xml ?

Comment: What is service-name in that

Comment: As Mohammed stated -  think service-name (in your javascript) should read service-title. service-name is not a node that is returned in the response

Comment: One thing I'd maybe be conscious of though, is that you are setting the value of the `serviceUrl` based on the result of `getServiceUrl`. With the service actually being an async call you cannot 100% rely on the value always being what you expect it to be if it's possible to call the service multiple times at a time or multiple times on the page. If one call hangs whilst another is made, the first call (the one hanging) may change the value in between it being set (second call) and the variable being used on your page/javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you think `service-name` should be `service-title` -

```
$(xml).find("service-title").each(function(){
            if($(this).text() == serviceName){
                var url = $(this).parent().find("service-url").text();
                return url;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
});
```

Comment: that is irrelevant to this question!

Comment: OP's XML didn't have service-name tag -

Comment: No it isn't at all Dimal. It's never going to find service-name if it doesn't exist. Barmar is correct with the scope of the xml node, but Mohammed is just as correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `$("service-name")` in the loop, it's looking in the regular DOM, not the downloaded XML. You need to use `$(this)` to get the element that `.each()` is processing.

```
function getServiceURL(serviceName) {
    $.get("/xml/ServiceUrls.xml", function(xml){
        alert ("success!"+xml);
        $(xml).find("service-name").each(function(){
            if($(this).text() == serviceName){
                var url = $(this).parent().find("service-url").text();
                return url;
            }else{
                return null;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I'm also not sure what you expect `return url` to do. The only thing `each()` does with the return value of the iteration function is check whether it's `false` or not -- if it is, the iteration stops. You can't return a value from `getServiceURL()` this way, because `$.get` is asynchronous -- it returned when the AJAX call started, it doesn't wait for the response.

Comment: I'm telling that the $get method doesn't execute the function(xml) and skips it to the end!

Comment: That's because `$(xml).find("service-name")` doesn't find anything, because there's no `<service-name>` in your XML.

Comment: Put a breakpoint before `$(xml)` and you'll see that the function does execute.

Comment: I changed the conflicting element name and yes I did add a breakpoint at the $.get method and inside the success function. but it skips the success function and goes straight to the end of the $.get method!

Comment: Try adding the alert like I just added to my answer.

Comment: I added an alert and it executes but after that it skips executing the rest!

Comment: How can you tell? The function doesn't do anything with the XML.